# 'Move to a new place' - different way of saying it

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

I want to find a way of saying something like...

> [...] I am willing to fund **my move to [insert country's name here]** myself to make up for [...]

... in a natural way.

I am pretty positive a native English speaker would understand what I mean by 'my move' but I am not sure whether it sounds natural - or even it is correct.

I know many ways of saying similar things in English, such as **I am going to move to Ohio** or **I moved to Canada last year** but I don't see how I can put it in a way where the act of moving is a 'noun' (?) so that I can say I'm willing to fund it myself.

Comment: Yes it's fine. 'Relocation' is also used in place of 'move'.

Comment: You didn’t ask, but unless you’ve got a particular reason for using “fund” (e.g., you’re planning on running a “fund my move” campaign with friends/family/[gullible] internet strangers) you could also consider replacing “fund” with “pay for” (especially with “my move to”) or perhaps “bear/incur the expense/costs of” with the more formal “my relocation to.”

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting point. I didn't realize 'fund' means only to raise money to accomplish a goal. Thought it could also mean 'pay for'. I love when ppl point out this sort of mistake, it's a great opportunity for me to learn subtle details about English :) I'll defo replace 'fund' by one of your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that your use of "fund" for "pay for" was a mistake or that it can **only** mean "raising money." Including "myself" as you did makes it pretty clear that it means "pay for [myself]," just as you thought. Sorry for the confusion! I just thought that "fund" sounded a bit 'weird' & that my suggestions might be a little more 'idiomatic.' You could also consider "finance." Also, to avoid repeating "**my**self" right after saying "**my** move/relocation", you could instead add "own" between "my" and "move" and omit "myself": "willing to fund/finance/pay for my **own** move."

Comment: Oh I get it now - thanks for pointing it out, really appreciate it. I hadn't noticed the repetition of 'my + myself' - so had not considered using 'own' instead of 'myself' - thanks for pointing this out too. Will update my letter with your suggestions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am willing to fund my relocation to France in order to facilitate etc...

"Relocation" is a an especially good word to use when you are talking about moving to another place for the purposes of employment.

Answer (score 1):

Examples that I can think of:

**Formal:**

> I will relocate to `country`

**Informal (North 'Murican way):**

> I will pull up stakes and go to `country`

**Standard**:

> I will move to `country`

Saying you're going to "move to `country`" is the most common, most natives, at least in America, say "move to".